# split string using different char and patterns

Tags: java, string, split

I have this string that contains html code :

```
String str ="<form action=''><span> First Name </span> <input type='text' id='fname' class='cls' size='40' required /> <span> [*]</span> <input type='submit' value='Submit' name='btn' /> <select name='slcEle' > <option value='opt'> Text</option> </select> <input type='radio' id='this'/> <button name='name' type='reset' value='val'> Text</button> <input type='range' min='0' max='100' name='grade'/> <button name='btnname' type='button'> Text</button>";
```

I want to split it, so that each html element be a separate string. The output could be array  that contains this:

> [0] = `<form action=''>`
>    [1] = `<span> First Name </span>`
>    [2] = `<input type='text' id='fname' class='cls' size='40' required />`
>    [3] = `<span> [*] </span>`
>    [4] = `<input type='submit' value='Submit' name='btn' />`
>    [5] = `<select name='slcEle' >`
>    [6] = `<option value='opt'> Text</option>`
>    [7] = `</select>`
>    and so on.

I can't use split function because as you see there are different characters and pattern for each string.

Can anyone help with this?

Comment: Obligatory caution about regex and HTML: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: 1) Use an HTML parser. 2) You haven't defined any rules. When do you decide to split a tag into separate items?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to split it, so that each html element be a separate string.

Here is an alternative answer using the `split()` method only. (ie no delimiter needed). Note that with this solution, text with blank characters only are preserved.

#### SAMPLE CODE

```
String str = "<form action=''><span> First Name </span> <input type='text' id='fname' class='cls' size='40' required /> <span> [*]</span> <input type='submit' value='Submit' name='btn' /> <select name='slcEle' > <option value='opt'> Text</option> </select> <input type='radio' id='this'/> <button name='name' type='reset' value='val'> Text</button> <input type='range' min='0' max='100' name='grade'/> <button name='btnname' type='button'> Text</button>";

String[] separateStrings = str.split("(?<=>)|(?=</)");

int len = separateStrings.length;
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    System.out.format("[%d] = %s\n", i, separateStrings[i]);
}
```

#### OUTPUT

```
[0] = <form action=''>
[1] = <span>
[2] =  First Name 
[3] = </span>
[4] =  <input type='text' id='fname' class='cls' size='40' required />
[5] =  <span>
[6] =  [*]
[7] = </span>
[8] =  <input type='submit' value='Submit' name='btn' />
[9] =  <select name='slcEle' >
[10] =  <option value='opt'>
[11] =  Text
[12] = </option>
[13] =  
[14] = </select>
[15] =  <input type='radio' id='this'/>
[16] =  <button name='name' type='reset' value='val'>
[17] =  Text
[18] = </button>
[19] =  <input type='range' min='0' max='100' name='grade'/>
[20] =  <button name='btnname' type='button'>
[21] =  Text
[22] = </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to handle html properly, I recommend you use a specific library that helps you. I recommend Jsoup

http://jsoup.org/

You'll find thousand times easier what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to split it, so that each html element be a separate string.

You can "mark" the initial string with a delimiter then split it.
In the sample code below, I ask the regex to ignore text with blank characters only.

#### SAMPLE CODE

```
String str = "<form action=''><span> First Name </span> <input type='text' id='fname' class='cls' size='40' required /> <span> [*]</span> <input type='submit' value='Submit' name='btn' /> <select name='slcEle' > <option value='opt'> Text</option> </select> <input type='radio' id='this'/> <button name='name' type='reset' value='val'> Text</button> <input type='range' min='0' max='100' name='grade'/> <button name='btnname' type='button'> Text</button>";

final String DELIMITER = "<--->";
String[] separateStrings = str //
                           .replaceAll("(?!\\s+)(<[^>]+>|[^/<>]+)", "$1" + DELIMITER) //
                           .split(DELIMITER);

int len = separateStrings.length;
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    System.out.format("[%d] = %s\n", i, separateStrings[i]);
}
```

#### OUTPUT

```
[0] = <form action=''>
[1] = <span>
[2] =  First Name 
[3] = </span>
[4] =  <input type='text' id='fname' class='cls' size='40' required />
[5] =  <span>
[6] =  [*]
[7] = </span>
[8] =  <input type='submit' value='Submit' name='btn' />
[9] =  <select name='slcEle' >
[10] =  <option value='opt'>
[11] =  Text
[12] = </option>
[13] =  </select>
[14] =  <input type='radio' id='this'/>
[15] =  <button name='name' type='reset' value='val'>
[16] =  Text
[17] = </button>
[18] =  <input type='range' min='0' max='100' name='grade'/>
[19] =  <button name='btnname' type='button'>
[20] =  Text
[21] = </button>
```